# Library Tess-two not working in Api 29 or higher

Tags: android, tesseract

In my App I am using the Tess-two (tess-two: 9.1. +) Library to do text recognition, and it works fine in Api 28 and earlier.

But when I test in emulators with Api 29 or higher, the application closes, more precisely in the execution of the method getOCRresult (detected = mTess.getUTF8Text (); this line).

Can someone know what changes there were in versions 29 or later so that the Tess-two library does not work correctly?

the Logcat shows: **A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR**

Answer (score 1):

App can't access directory directly except public path from Android 10 (29).
You can control directory like before if you use `requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the Manifest.xml. But it will work until Android 10 (29). You have to change source from Android 11 (30).